# Is StackOverflow an appropriate place to ask questions related to mobile development?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, site-recommendation

I looked for, and was surprised not to find, a StackExchange "Mobile Applications" site. Is StackOverflow the best place to ask questions related to Android/iOS development, or does there exist a more suitable site?

Comment: What kind of questions?

Comment: If you have programming questions, the [ios]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios and [android]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android tags are both extremely active. Note that business-side questions about app stores or sales-related issues are still off topic for the site.

Comment: @BradLarson Thanks. Right, and I see that the Startup Business beta never reached a critical mass. Perhaps a site like Quora is a better fit for non-technical/business-side questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your question is revealing.

1. Stack Overflow is not a forum.  Most of the things you learned participating in forum environments won't work here.
2. Stack Overflow is not for discussions. Most of the tools here are designed to minimize the noise factor, and discussions don't really fit well into that model.

If you have a *specific* software development question having to do with code/implementation or programming tools, you can ask it on Stack Overflow, and tag it Android or iOS.  If you have a specific software development question having to do with software design or some other conceptual topic, you can ask it at Programmers.

The Help Center article that describes what kinds of questions that can be asked on  Stack Overflow is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).  The Help Center article that describes what kinds of questions that can be asked on  Programmers is [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: You're right. I should have worded included the wording "...questions related to..." in the title. Understood that the best way of posing questions is to tag them with the appropriate OS.